# Storing Unique Values from Excel file into separate Dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, unique

I have a massive csv file I'm working with here. What I want is to be able to store all unique values in a certain column into a dataframe. For a small example, if I had:

```
1   a   
2   b
3   c
4   a
5   b
```

I would want my code to sort this into x amount of dataframes where x would be the amount of unique values from column two (in this example that would be 3).

What I did is find the name of every unique variable in my desired column and did vectorization. Which would be:

```
    DF1 <- Data[Data$Column2 == "a",]
    DF2 <- Data[Data$Column2 == "b",]
    DF3 <- Data[Data$Column2 == "c",]
```

But that was super tedious, and since I have way more than just 3 unique values it took me waaaaay too long. There has got to be an easier way to do it.
Maybe using loops? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: How many rows and columns does your data frame have?

Comment: It is constantly changing because I always have to add more data to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `split` to split the data.frame into separate data.frame in a `list` and then use `lapply` to loop over the `list` and write the files as `csv`

```
lst1 <- split(Data, Data$Column2)
lapply(names(lst1), function(nm) write.csv(lst1[[nm]], paste0(nm, ".csv"),
     quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE))
```

---

By doing the `split`, we effectively reduce the burden of naming multiple objects in the global environment, reduce the clutter, and reduce the time in finding those objects and saving one by one with `write.csv`

Comment: Wow that works perfectly. Will I be able to index the list? In my excel file the data I am actually interested in would be in the columns 3 and on, but I just needed to separate based off of column 2.

Comment: @Beebs Yes, you can use index as well `lapply(seq_along(lst1), function(i) lst1[[i]])`